# c# mongodb cursor not found

Tags: c#, mongodb

I wonder why I got an exception telling me 'cursor not found'.
I have 5 million data in the server, i have my program to fetch all those but it stops after hours parsing those and getting eans in the loop.

```
var libris = LibriCollection.FindAll().SetFields("doc.product.productidentifier");
            List<string> eans = new List<string>();
            foreach (var product in libris)
            {

                eans.Add(product.doc["product"]["productidentifier"]["b244"].AsString;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You need to disable to cursor timeout.](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-397)

```
cursor.SetFlags(QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout);
```