# MongoDB, convert element data type from numeric string to number for a large collection (3kk)

Tags: json, mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a large 3kk mongodb collection for which i need to convert one element from numeric string to number.

I'm using a mongo-shell script which works for small 100k element collection, please see below the script:

```
db.SurName.find().forEach(function(tmp){
    tmp.NUMBER = parseInt(tmp.NUMBER);
    db.SurName.save(tmp);
})
```

But after a dozen minutes of work I got an error (the error occurs even if the collection is smaller like 1kk):

```
MongoDB Enterprise Test-shard-0:PRIMARY> db.SurName.find().forEach(function(tmp){
...         tmp.NUMBER = parseInt(tmp.NUMBER);
... db.SurName.save(tmp);
...     })
2020-01-18T16:59:21.173+0100 E  QUERY    [js] Error: command failed: {
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1579363161, 14),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "cursor id 4811116025485863761 not found",
        "code" : 43,
        "codeName" : "CursorNotFound",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1579363161, 14),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"EemWWenbArSdh4dTFa0aNcfAPms="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("6748451824648323073")
                }
        }
} : getMore command failed: {
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1579363161, 14),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "cursor id 4811116025485863761 not found",
        "code" : 43,
        "codeName" : "CursorNotFound",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1579363161, 14),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"EemWWenbArSdh4dTFa0aNcfAPms="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("6748451824648323073")
                }
        }
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:583:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:673:16
DBCommandCursor.prototype._runGetMoreCommand@src/mongo/shell/query.js:802:5
DBCommandCursor.prototype._hasNextUsingCommands@src/mongo/shell/query.js:832:9
DBCommandCursor.prototype.hasNext@src/mongo/shell/query.js:840:16
DBQuery.prototype.hasNext@src/mongo/shell/query.js:288:13
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:493:12
@(shell):1:1
```

Is there a way to do this better/right?

EDIT:
The obj schema:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e241b98c7cab1382c7c9d95"},
"SURNAME":"KOWALSKA",
"SEX":"KOBIETA",
"TERYT":"0201011",
"NUMBER":"51",
"COMMUNES":"BOLESŁAWIEC",
"COUNTIES":"BOLESŁAWIECKI",
"PROVINCES":"DOLNOŚLĄSKIE"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB CursorNotFound Error on collection.find() for a few hundred small records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526688/mongodb-cursornotfound-error-on-collection-find-for-a-few-hundred-small-record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and fast solution is to use `mongodb aggregation` with [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator.

Equivalent to:

```
insert into new_table
select * from old_table
```

We convert `NUMBER` field with `$toInt` (MongoDB version >= 4.0) operator and store documents in the `SurName2` collection. Once we have finished, we just drop old collection and rename `SurName2` collection to `SurName`.

```
db.SurName.aggregate([
  {$addFields:{
    NUMBER : {$toInt:"$NUMBER"}
  }},
  {$out: "SurName2"}
])
```

Once you check everything is fine, execute these sentences:

```
db.SurName.drop()
db.SurName2.renameCollection("SurName")
```

Comment: Your solution works. Is there a way for doing this on the same collection (without copying)? The thing is, I don't have room for mirroring the collection. Will it be: db.SurName.aggregate([
  {$addFields:{
    NUMBER : {$toInt:"$NUMBER"}
  }}
]) ?

Comment: aggregation was not made for this purpose..

Comment: @szelek you may export Surname collection, modify NUMBER to integer: search `NUMBER" :"(.*?)"` replace NUMBER" : $1 . Then import again with --drop option

Comment: @Valijon - feels like an overkill to me....

Comment: Not able to import or export such large json ;(

Comment: `monogoexport` / `mongoimport`??

Comment: @Szelek try: `path/to/mongoexport -d database -c SurName --out path/to/SurName.json`

Comment: Finally i have done it by partial import via mongo-shell import tool mongoimport --host Test-shard-0/test-shard-00-00-gceee.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-00-01-gceee.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-00-02-gceee.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username <username> --password <password> --authenticationDatabase admin --db EngineeringProject --collection SurName --type json --file "C:\Users\Ja\Desktop\ConverterCSVtoJSON\STAT_NAZWISKA_KOBIETY3.json" --jsonArray

Comment: @Szelek Excellent. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

** **EDIT - START** **

Googling "cursor id not found code 43", yielded this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51602507/2279082

** **EDIT - END** **

I don't have your data set so I cannot test my answer very well. That being said, you can try to `Update` the specific field (see about update in the docs: [db.collection.update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/))

So your script will look like this:

```
db.SurName.find({}, {NUMBER: 1}).forEach(function(tmp){
    db.SurName.update({_id: tmp._id}, {$set: {NUMBER: parseInt(tmp.NUMBER)}});
})
```

Let me know if it helps or if needs an edit

Comment: It's giving me the same error.

Comment: Assuming it is a memory issue, and all you need is the `_id` and the `NUMBER` fields, you can run the `find` part as follows: `db.SurName.find({}, {NUMBER: 1})` (I edited my answer to match). The first `{}` is to match all collection items. The second one will return just the `_id` and `NUMBER` fields

Comment: Googling "cursor id not found code 43", yielded this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51602507/2279082